# Find all nodes that are not in cycle in a graph

Tags: php, algorithm, graph

The graph is given below.. The first set says the nodes and other set gives all the bridges.

How to find a particular node in cycle or not.
{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M},{(E,D),(D,A),(A,B),(B,C),(A,C),(C,F),(F,G),(G,H),(H,L),(G,L),(H,M),(M,B),(G,I),(I,J),(J,K)}

Here, E,D,I,J,K are the nodes required(not in cycle). Here E, and K are for sure as they have one branch only How to traverse other D,I and J.

Ex:

In shown graph A,D and F are nodes not in cycle while other are. 
[image: Graph]

Comment: How can nodes be cycle? Did you mean nodes not part of cycle

Comment: Not Cycle in a cycle ..

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer if the graph example matches the textual example that you are talking mostly about in your question.

Comment: What you're looking for is strongly connected components. You can use Tarjan's algorithm (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) to find all the SCCs. Then, for each SCC, if only one node belongs to it, then that node is not part of a cycle, otherwise, it is.

Comment: yes text and diagram are not matching

Comment: I tried to give you two examples .. :(

Comment: It can be done like Filipe wrote. If node has less than two neighbours than it is not in cycle. Remove it from graph. Repeat check while there are nodes with degree <= 1.

Comment: @Ante Thanks .. It passed some test cases but now remove the bridge  (BM)in given set , The node F is not in cycle but has two bridges connecting C and G

Comment: @atjoshi Ups, I forget about bridges :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your approach I have done this ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Challenge I</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
ini_set( 'xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 4 );
$Input1            = 2;
$Input2            = '({A,B,C},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)}),({A,B,C,D,E},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(E,D),(D,A)}),({A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M},{(E,D),(D,A),(A,B),(B,C),(A,C),(C,F),(F,G),(G,H),(H,L),(G,L),(H,M),(G,I),(I,J),(J,K)})';
$Input2            = '(' . $Input2 . ')';
$Input2            = preg_replace( '/([^\(\)\{\}\[\],]+)/', '"$1"', $Input2 );
$Input2            = preg_replace( '/[\{\(]/', '[', $Input2 );
$Input2            = preg_replace( '/[\}\)]/', ']', $Input2 );
$Input2            = json_decode( $Input2, true );
//var_dump($Input2);
$finalOutputString = NULL;
$newarray          = $Input2;
foreach ( $Input2 as $testcases ) {
    $newarray      = $testcases;
    $critical_count = 1;
    $outputString  = NULL;
    while ( $critical_count != 0 ) {
        $testcases                = $newarray;
        $arrCriticalNodeandBridge = array( );
        $critical_count            = 1;
        $m                        = 0;
        foreach ( $testcases[ 0 ] as $Icelands ) {
            $i                                       = 0;
            $bridgeListFromIcelandarray[ $Icelands ] = array( );
            foreach ( $testcases[ 1 ] as $Bridges ) {
                if ( in_array( $Icelands, $Bridges ) ) {
                    $bridgeListFromIcelandarray[ $Icelands ][ $i++ ] = $Bridges;
                } //in_array( $Icelands, $Bridges )
            } //$testcases[ 1 ] as $Bridges
            $countval = count( $bridgeListFromIcelandarray[ $Icelands ] );
            if ( $countval === 1 ) {
                $Bridges                                    = $bridgeListFromIcelandarray[ $Icelands ][ 0 ];
                $arrCriticalNodeandBridge[ $m ][ 'node' ]   = $Icelands;
                $arrCriticalNodeandBridge[ $m ][ 'bridge' ] = $Bridges;
                $Bridges                                    = json_encode( $Bridges );
                $Bridges                                    = preg_replace( '/"(.*?)"/', '$1', $Bridges );
                $Bridges                                    = preg_replace( '/\[/', '(', $Bridges );
                $Bridges                                    = preg_replace( '/\]/', ')', $Bridges );
                if ( $outputString === NULL )
                    $outputString = $Bridges;
                else
                    $outputString = $outputString . ',' . $Bridges;
                $m++;
            } //$countval === 1
        } //$testcases[ 0 ] as $Icelands
        //var_dump( $bridgeListFromIcelandarray);
        //var_dump( $arrCriticalNodeandBridge);
        $critical_count = count( $arrCriticalNodeandBridge );
        foreach ( $arrCriticalNodeandBridge as $v ) {
            unset( $bridgeListFromIcelandarray[ $v[ 'node' ] ] );
            foreach ( $testcases[ 0 ] as $k => $node ) {
                if ( $node == $v[ 'node' ] ) {
                    unset( $testcases[ 0 ][ $k ] );
                    $testcases[ 0 ] = array_values( $testcases[ 0 ] );
                } //$node == $v[ 'node' ]
            } //$testcases[ 0 ] as $k => $node
            foreach ( $testcases[ 1 ] as $k => $node ) {
                if ( $node == $v[ 'bridge' ] ) {
                    unset( $testcases[ 1 ][ $k ] );
                    $testcases[ 1 ] = array_values( $testcases[ 1 ] );
                } //$node == $v[ 'bridge' ]
            } //$testcases[ 1 ] as $k => $node
        } //$arrCriticalNodeandBridge as $v
        $newarray = $testcases;
    } //$critical_count != 0
    //var_dump($newarray);
    $checkgraph = $newarray[ 1 ];
    foreach ( $checkgraph as $k => $c ) {
        $newgraphsearch = $checkgraph;
        $todel          = $newgraphsearch[ $k ];
        unset( $newgraphsearch[ $k ] );
        $newgraphsearch        = array_values( $newgraphsearch );
        $finaldepthsearchgraph = array( );
        $deletebranch          = json_encode( $todel );
        $number                = 1;
        foreach ( $bridgeListFromIcelandarray as $k => $bd ) {
            $letter     = $k;
            $array_node = array( );
            foreach ( $bd as $k => $h ) {
                if ( $todel == $h ) {
                    unset( $bd[ $k ] );
                    $bd = array_values( $bd );
                } //$todel == $h
            } //$bd as $k => $h
            foreach ( $bd as $k => $h ) {
                foreach ( $h as $nodearray ) {
                    if ( $nodearray !== $letter ) {
                        array_push( $array_node, $nodearray );
                    } //$nodearray !== $letter
                } //$h as $nodearray
            } //$bd as $k => $h
            $finaldepthsearchgraph[ $letter ][ 'vertex' ]     = $letter;
            $finaldepthsearchgraph[ $letter ][ 'visited' ]    = false;
            $finaldepthsearchgraph[ $letter ][ 'neighbours' ] = $array_node;
            $number++;
        } //$bridgeListFromIcelandarray as $k => $bd
        //var_dump($finaldepthsearchgraph);
        $firstnode   = $newarray[ 0 ][ 0 ];
        $returnvalue = breadthFirstSearch( $finaldepthsearchgraph, $firstnode );
        if ( $returnvalue != count( $newarray[ 0 ] ) ) {
            $deletebranch = preg_replace( '/"(.*?)"/', '$1', $deletebranch );
            $deletebranch = preg_replace( '/\[/', '(', $deletebranch );
            $deletebranch = preg_replace( '/\]/', ')', $deletebranch );
            if ( $outputString === NULL )
                $outputString = $deletebranch;
            else
                $outputString = $outputString . ',' . $deletebranch;
        } //$returnvalue != count( $newarray[ 0 ] )
    } //$checkgraph as $k => $c
    if ( $outputString === NULL )
        $outputString = 'NA';
    $outputString = '{' . $outputString . '}';
    if ( $finalOutputString === NULL )
        $finalOutputString = $outputString;
    else
        $finalOutputString = $finalOutputString . ',' . $outputString;
} //$Input2 as $testcases
if ( count( $Input2 ) != 1 )
    $finalOutputString = '{' . $finalOutputString . '}';
echo $finalOutputString;
function breadthFirstSearch( $list, $firstnode )
{
    $queue = array( );
    array_unshift( $queue, $list[ $firstnode ] );
    $list[ $firstnode ][ 'visited' ] = true;
    $str                             = NULL;
    while ( sizeof( $queue ) ) {
        $vertex = array_pop( $queue );
        $str .= $vertex[ 'vertex' ];
        foreach ( $vertex[ 'neighbours' ] as $neighbour ) {
            if ( !$list[ $neighbour ][ 'visited' ] ) {
                $list[ $neighbour ][ 'visited' ] = true;
                array_unshift( $queue, $list[ $neighbour ] );
            } //!$list[ $neighbour ][ 'visited' ]
        } //$vertex[ 'neighbours' ] as $neighbour
    } //sizeof( $queue )
    return strlen( $str );
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact solution but possible approach..
Using Ante method to simplify graph and then adding this algo.
It passed a bit more test cases .... If you find any more test cases please share .. to check the validity

```
<?php
$nodes = '{A,B,C,D,E}'; // It is just One Test Case
$bridges = '{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(E,D),(D,A)}'; // It is for just one test case
$graph = $nodes.','.$bridges;

function graphStringtoArrayObj()
    {
    // CODE TO CONVERT THE STRING TO ARRAY AND MANIPULATE THE GRAPH HERE
    // preg_replace can be used like in function criticalBridges();
    }
function graphArrayObjtoString()
    {
    // CODE TO CONVERT THE ARRAY TO STRING AND MANIPULATE THE GRAPH HERE
    }   
function simplificationofGraph( string $graph_string)
    {
        // code for simplification of the graph by deleting all the sure critical bridges and nodes
        // Node that has just one bridge 
          $simplified_Value = simplificationofGraph($a);
        // Condition Check : Two cases
        //Case I
            // If just One Node is left after recursive simplification return single node 

        //Case II 
            //return : Simplified Graph 
    }
function checkNodeInCycle($node)
    {
        $nodecheck = $node;
        $stack1 = array();// For putting possible nodes
        $stack2 = array();// For putting the nodes connected to the $nodecheck but not in $stack1;
        $flag = 0;

        //START WHILE
        //while return value from simplificationofGraph($graph_updated) is not a single node
            array_push($stack2, $nodecheckkat);
            arary_pop($stack2);
            //$nodecheckat = popped element from stack2;
            //traverse starts 
            array_push($stack1, $nodecheckat);
            // Check all nodes connected to $nodecheckat.
            // check if $nodecheckat->nodesat in_arrray($stack1) 
            foreach($nodecheckat->nodeat as $nodeelem)
            {
                if(in_arrray($nodeelem , $stack1) )
                {
                    if($nodeelem === $nodecheck)
                    {
                        // this node is in loop and we can break here to check another node of initial simplified graph
                        $flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $flag_stupidnode = 1;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    array_push($nodeelem,$stack2);

                }
            }
            if($flag_stupidnode === 1)
            {
                // this means the $nodecheck->node element are already there in the stack1 and have been traversed this means its false loop
                // this node and the bridges connected to it can be removed
                // remove all bridges and then make a new graph 


                // Update the stack1 and Stack2 by removing this node
                simplificationofGraph($graph_updated);
            }

        // END WHILE

        if($flag == 0 )
         {// 'this node is the critical note not in a cycle';}

    }

function criticalBridges($graph) // This gives all the bridge from the node  and we can find the node having just one bridge . take node and the bridge and remove that node and bridge and simplify the graph.
    {
        $Input2 = '('.$graphstring.')';
        $Input2 = preg_replace('/([^\(\)\{\}\[\],]+)/', '"$1"', $Input2);
        $Input2 = preg_replace('/[\{\(]/', '[', $Input2);
        $Input2 = preg_replace('/[\}\)]/', ']', $Input2);
        $Input2 = json_decode($Input2, true);
        $bridgeListFromIcelandarray = array();
        $finalOutputString = NULL;
        foreach($Input2 as $testcases)
        {   
            $outputString = NULL;
            foreach($testcases[0] as $Icelands)
            {
                $i = 0;
                $bridgeListFromIcelandarray[$Icelands] = array();
                foreach($testcases[1] as $Bridges)
                {
                    if(in_array($Icelands,$Bridges) )
                        $bridgeListFromIcelandarray[$Icelands][$i++] = $Bridges;
                }
                $countval = count($bridgeListFromIcelandarray[$Icelands]);
                if($countval === 1)
                {   
                    $Bridges = $bridgeListFromIcelandarray[$Icelands][0];
                    $Bridges = json_encode($Bridges);
                    $Bridges = preg_replace('/"(.*?)"/','$1',$Bridges);
                    $Bridges = preg_replace('/\[/', '(',$Bridges);
                    $Bridges = preg_replace('/\]/', ')',$Bridges);
                    if($outputString === NULL)
                        $outputString = $Bridges;
                    else
                        $outputString = $outputString .','. $Bridges; 
                }
            }
            if($outputString === NULL)
                 $outputString = 'NA';
            $outputString = '{'. $outputString . '}';

            if($finalOutputString === NULL)
                $finalOutputString = $outputString;
            else
                $finalOutputString =    $finalOutputString .','. $outputString;
        var_dump($bridgeListFromIcelandarray);
        }

        if (count($Input2) != 1)
            $finalOutputString = '{'. $finalOutputString . '}';             
        return $finalOutputString; 


    }





?>
```